# Append a string after digits in a file using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file containing these lines:

```
John
Some String 1234
Mary
another string 3445
Tom
Cat Dog 2367
```

i.e. every alternate line ends with number, and there are no numbers anywhere else.
I want to add < /br> tag just after the number so that output is like:

```
John
Some String 1234</br>
Mary
another string 3445</br>
...
```

I tried using sed command as:

```
 sed -i 's/[0-9]+/1<\/br>/'  filename.html
```

but it errors out.
How do I get this done?

Comment: (1) If using `+`, tell `sed` to use extended RE.  (2) Make use of capture groups and backreferences.  (3) You may also want to read about anchors in RE.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
sed -i.bak 's~[0-9]\+$~&</br>~' file
```

Now file content will be:

```
cat file

John
Some String 1234</br>
Mary
another string 3445</br>
Tom
Cat Dog 2367</br>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this one:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\+\)$/\1<br\/>/' your.txt
```

Short explanation:

Numbers with a various length `[0-9]\+`at the of the line `$` gets matched into a matching-group `\( ... \)`. It will get replaced by the value of that matching group `\1` plus the `<br\/>` tag. Don't miss that I've escaped several characters with the backslash `\` because they have a special meaning in the pattern.

Comment: your command should be `sed 's/\([0-9]\+\)$/\1<\/br>/g' file`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Why? There can be just one number *at the end of the line*

Comment: op wants `</br>` not `<br/>`

Comment: `</br>` is not a valid html tag

Comment: Then why he wants that?

Comment: It's obvious that this was by accident (or lack of knowledge)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sed -ri.bak '/[0-9]+$/ s/$/<\/br>/g' filename.html
```

Comment: `g` tells sed to do the substitution for every occurrence of the RE on the line but you're matching on end of line so there can only be 1 occurrence on the line so the `g` does nothing at best.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, I was missing `()` around the matched pattern.

So it is like:

```
sed -i 's/\([0-9][0-9]*\)/\L\1<\/br>/I'  filename.html
```

Comment: And why end the command with I? Why group the RE instead of referencing it with &? Why switch from RE+ to RERE* notation instead of adding -r? See @anubhava's answer for the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the numbers are always at the end of even numbered lines, *GNU* `sed`'s extended range addresses are sufficient:

```
sed -i.bak '2~2s#$#</br>#' file
```

Output:

```
John
Some String 1234</br>
Mary
another string 3445</br>
Tom
Cat Dog 2367</br>
```